# How to implement NRF52840 BLE DFU using Zephyr RTOS?

Tags: microcontroller, bluetooth-low-energy, rtos

I am using Zephyr RTOS to run an NRF52840 module using NRF Connect SDK V2.2.0. Can anyone please indicate on how to implement BLE DFU with Zephyr. My current application already has BLE read and write characteristics enabled to send and receive data to an android device over BLE.

I managed to write code for the controller using Segger to perform BLE DFU using nrfutil and NRF connect for desktop to send an image with matching keys to the controller over BLE but cannot find a solution for the same result but using Zephyr RTOS.

Comment: This is not like "electrical engineering" question. Nordic or Zephyr forum would be better for this kind of help.

Comment: Ask on the devzone from Nordic. I've gotten excellent support there.